# sharepoint search boolean managed property

Tags: search, query, managed-property, search-query

I have a managed property `isActive` which happens to be a Boolean. I am creating a search query and I only want the ones that are active so `isActive:true` however I am having trouble with the correct syntax.
Can anyone tell me this I am using sharepoint 2013

Comment: which sharepoint version are you using 2010/2013?

Comment: edit has been made

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `isActive=1` this means it equals true. `isActive:1` is a contains query.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Waquas, isn't that for the asker to decide? I believe it does answer the question.

Comment: it is too short and may be it provide the answer...in many cases you leave this as comment if asker says its work then you can put into the answer.

Comment: When an answer actually answers the questions who is to say it's too short? I'll wait for the asker.

Comment: i appreciate your level of confidence...